# Does the .Net (core) runtime have application lifecycle events?

Tags: .net, .net-core

I would like to have events for my application's lifecycle, at the very least one just before the actual `Main(string[] args)` method is started, one after it has finished, and potentially one when the application ends through other means. The icing on the cake would be events for each DLL loaded and unloaded.

If I search for application lifecycle events for .Net, Google tends to give me pages on ASP.Net, which I'm not targeting, or Microsoft Product Lifecycle info...

Comment: what do you want to do with them, if there are such `events`? you want write C# event handlers in your application?

Comment: Before `Main` starts is just putting code at the very beggining of it, just after it finishes enclose the whole thing in a `try`/`finally` block  There are no other means of exiting a program other than finishing its `Main` method (killing it of course leaves no code to run). What's your real intention in such events?

Comment: @stuartd I explicitly said I'm not targeting ASP.Net.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to provide a ClassLibrary that will scan the application (EXE and DLLs) for classes or methods annotated in a certain way with custom Attributes. This naturally needs to be done before the application has started, or I'm too late. I guess being able to hook into new and delete (Dispose?) would also help.

Comment: You mean a class library that will scan any application that it is referenced by?

Comment: @DavidG Exactly. This is not particularly unusual if you want to save the library's users a lot of work in explicitly enumerating things. A [DI container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection) can collect all classes that are candidates for injection without any ugly XML files or long lists of configuration boilerplate code. This is exactly the kind of usage that Attributes are perfect for. However, we _do_ need to be able to hook into the application's startup sequence.

Comment: Normally I would expect such a library to contain some sort of `Initialize` method where I can tell it that I'm ready to use it. I find very invasive to have the library code run without any explicit invocation.

Comment: @Alejandro I already acknowledged that I wanted this to happen by adding/installing the appropriate NuGet packages into my project. It only adds to my work and additionally can cause further time wasted because I now have to check that I do both actions for any library, without any extra benefits. If you don't trust the package to start with, why add it to your project? Now if this is about "I don't trust the writer of the library to do what I want," then you haven't truly experienced the blissful ease of use that comes from using the power of Attributes.

Comment: Have you looked at [`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyLoad`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyload?view=net-5.0)?